# Theorems in complex analysis.

Tags: complex-analysis

I need help to prove these theorems:
1)If $\mathcal f $ is continuous on $\mathbb C $  and $\mathcal f(z) = f(2z)  \forall z \in \mathbb C $ then $\mathcal f $ is constant . 
2)If $\mathcal f $  is entire and $\mathcal f(2z)=2f(z)$ then $ \exists $ $\lambda $ such that $\mathcal f(z)=\lambda\mathcal z
$.

Comment: Hint: Rewrite 1) as $f(z) = f(z/2) = f(z/4) = \ldots$.
Problem 2 is unclear. $\lambda = 1$???

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $f(z/2^n) =f(z)$ and $\lim f(z/2^n) =f(0)$

Comment: That is one "monster" of a hint.  ;-))  but +1